# lsusb - where device description comes from

Tags: usb, input-devices, devices, lsusb

For one of my attached USB devices (2773:0104) I see no description in **lsusb** command output:

```
user@Thinkpad-Laptop:~/binaries$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 036: ID 2773:0104
```

Where USB description is comming from, is it from device driver or is it stored in the hardware itself ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The device identifies itself only with the ID value. This is made up with a 2-byte code (4 hex digits) identifying the manufacturer (eg, `0a5c` for Broadcom), followed by a 2-byte product identity (`217f`).

Ubuntu uses the database maintained [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-ids.html). If you have a piece of hardware not identified by the current version of this file, you could tell them about it. The manufacturer ID `2773` currently has no entry.

Comment: Does Windows also has such a database ?

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the id given through the usbbus from the device.
The description comes from `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids`.

To get such an information I advise you to simply use `man lsusb`.