# How does a Linux operating system recognize USB drive brand and other info?

Tags: usb

When I use commands like `lsusb`, `sudo fdisk -l`, the output shows the brand that made the USB and other details, but I do not get how Linux OS recognizes it.

Comment: I am not a developer but I think the drivers for these devices make this possible.

Comment: This will help: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids

Comment: @Jos answer it or someone else will :+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lsusb - where device description comes from](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227881/lsusb-where-device-description-comes-from)

Comment: @Rinzwind It was answered 7 years ago... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a list of USB vendors and devices, built into a separate package `usbutils`. When you connect a USB device, the USB driver reads the vendor ID string from the device, and looks it up in the vendor table. Same for the device ID.

The official list is maintained by [the USB organisation](https://usb.org). Here's [the list itself](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids.) in readable format.

Comment: The table used to look up vendors and devices on your local system is stored in `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` and part of the `usbutils` package.

Comment: Thank you @ByteCommander. I just spent some time trying to locate it in the kernel source. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Just had a quick look at `man lsusb` - the file is mentioned there ;)

Comment: You can change `usb.ids` if your manufacturer's name comes up blank or is misleading. I've had to do this a couple of times in the past. Once for a USB hub another time for a smartphone.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix So you're saying the actual (human readable) list is parsed? There is not even a separate little database? Funny. However, it allows you to change your USB strings on the fly, which is useful.

Comment: @Jos Yes it's a config file. You can edit it: `wc /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` gives you: `19642  78701 551472 /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` So about 19k lines of manufacturer and device names. Use `less /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` to have a quick peek.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that that file is identical to the second link I gave in my answer.